# Help understanding the result of a formula

Tags: calculus

I need some help understand the middle section of this formula.

$$OA^2 = (100-40)^2 + 50^2=10^2(61)\to OA = r = 10\sqrt{61} $$

and  $$\sin(\angle OCB ) = \frac{30}{r} = \frac{3}{\sqrt{61}}, \cos(\angle OCB ) = \frac{\sqrt{52}}{\sqrt{61}}$$

vertical height of $C$ from the center is $$r\cos(\angle OCB ) =10\sqrt{52}, BC = 10\sqrt{52} - 60=12.111$$

I can work out all except for how the 52 was calculated. Can anyone explain how this was achieved?: $$\sqrt{52}$$

Comment: $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$, so $\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{61}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{61}}\right)^2=1$, hence $u^2=52=61-3^2$

Answer (score 2):

Answered by Alexey Burdin. Please see his answer above in comment area of my question. It is clear and easy to understand.

$\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$, so $\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{61}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{61}}\right)^2=1$, hence $u^2=52=61-3^2$.